# Union in HoneySQL

Tags: clojure, honeysql

Would like to make a `UNION` (MySQL, but PostgreSQL has them too) in a HoneySQL query.  [Searching the source code](https://github.com/jkk/honeysql/blob/72784452b93541fe42eeeeaf19c246b8c0ed433b/src/honeysql/helpers.clj#L234) suggests it might be possible, but does not suggest an obvious approach to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no helper function, but you can use sql/build:

```
(sql/format (sql/build :union [(-> (select :*)
                               (from :table1))
                           (-> (select :*)
                               (from :table2))]))

=> ["(SELECT * FROM table1) UNION (SELECT * FROM table2)"]
```

This helper could work, although it's not quite idiomatic with the other helpers:

```
(defhelper union [m1 m2]
  {:union [m1 m2]})

(sql/format (union (-> (select :*) (from :table1))
                   (-> (select :*) (from :table2)))
```